# Printing a single backslash in haskell using ShowString

Tags: haskell

I am trying to return a string including a single backslash in Haskell, I am using `showString "\\" []`

My function type is Int -> String -> String
however this is outputting two backslashes.

How can I return a string with a single backslash?

Comment: This does not makes much sense, since `showString "\\"` is a function that expects another `String` parameter.

Comment: The string `"\\"` is precisely the string composed of a single backslash (try `length "\\"` and `head "\\"`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want to use:

```
putStrLn (showString "\\" [])
```

Within the GHCi REPL when you enter a value, vs an IO action, is is automatically rendered using `show` which will then escape some characters.

For example:

```
Prelude> showString "\\" []
"\\"
Prelude> putStrLn $ showString "\\" []
\
```

Answer (score 2):

`showString` has type:

```
showString :: String -> String -> String
```

so that means you need to provide two strings (you provide one together with an empty string). Basically `showString` concatenates the two strings (which is not a problem). The function `showString "\\" ""` *returns* a string with a single backslash, but it does not *print* anything (since `showString`) is a function that only returns content.

Now there is a difference between the *content* of a string, and its *representation*. New lines, tabs, unicode characters, etc. are *represented* by *escaping*: one uses a backslash followed by some pattern. This pattern is not part of the *content* of the string.

Nevertheless `showString` does *not* print anything. It returns a `String`, and that string is shown as a string literal by the interactive console.

In order to print the *content* (not its representation) of a string, you can use [**`putStrLn :: String -> IO ()`**](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.10.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:putStrLn) or [**`putStr :: String -> IO ()`**](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.10.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:putStr) in case you want to omit the new line.

This then produces:

```
Prelude> putStrLn "\\"
\
```

`PutStrLn` will for a given `String` produce an `IO ()` that will print the string to the standard output channel (`stdout`). It is somewhat equivalent to `print(..)` in Python, `System.out.println(..)` in Java, and `Console.WriteLine(..)` in C#.

Comment: I'm still unsure of how I can use the showString method to return a string containing a single '\'

Comment: @JamesHamish: well the function *returns* a string where the *content* it a single backslash, but the *representation* of a string escapes that.