# Trying to print backslash, instead getting two

Tags: haskell, escaping

I have a function that converts a lambda Expr to a String (pretty printing). The issue is I want to print a single backslash "\" before a list of bound variables. To do so I believe I need to escape it, so my string could be formatted as follows:

```
"\\" ++ other String stuff
```

The problem is I get that literal output - two backslashes. I'm not entirely sure how to fix that so if anybody has any pointers it'd be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are you producing your output with `show` (including `print` or just evaluating it at the ghci prompt)? `show` is designed to produce **Haskell syntax** for your value, not to pretty print it for display to an end user. So, since you need to escape backslashes in strings in Haskell syntax `show` will give you extra backslashes to do the escaping.

Comment: If I do, for instance, show "\\" in Prelude I get "\"\\\\\"" as an output. At the moment I literally have it as a function Expr -> String, with the = being what I put in my question.

Comment: It is fine as it is. `show` on strings is supposed to add quotes and escape funny chars. Try `putStrLn yourString` to print it raw. You'll discover that your pretty printing function is OK. Just avoid `show` or `print` to check your final output, or interpret their result as if it is escaped.

Comment: Ok that works, thank you very much!

Comment: Surely this is already a dup of... something.

Comment: Does https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47541845/printing-a-single-backslash-in-haskell-using-showstring/47542700#47542700 resolve your confusion?